# Skype smileys REGEXP patterns where/how to get?

Tags: regex, skype

I would like to understand the patterns they are using for their smileys.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "patterns"?

Comment: Regexp patterns for replacement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If emoticons are only replaced if surrounded by whitespace or (presumably) at start/end of a line/string, then you can use a series of regexes.

Using this list (taken from http://www.skype-forum.com/ftopic13197.html),...

[image: List of smileys]

you can construct these like this:

```
(?<=^|\s)<<smiley regex>>(?=\s|$)
```

will match `<<smiley regex>>` only if it's on its own.

Examples for `<<smiley regex>>`:

```
:-?\)    :-?\(       :-?D         8\)
;\(      \(sweat\)   :\|          :\*
:\$      :\^\)       \|-\)        \|\(
;\)      \]:\)       \(talk\)     \(yawn\)
\(doh\)  :@          \(wasntme\)  \(party\)
```

etc. - you'll need to escape a lot of special-meaning characters for use in a regex. Your language might have a `re.escape()` function for this.

Comment: Simple replacement is not enough, that's why i have started the topic. :) Try yourself in skype

Comment: Why isn't it enough? I don't have Skype installed, and I don't plan to. Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: For example if :) smile is surrounded by text from both sides it's not replaced with icon, only if it's surrounded by whitespaces. That means that they were using some additional pattern rules

Comment: - test:)test will not replace smile with icon, test :)test will not replace as well, but test :) test will replace it

Comment: Could you explain a bit this regexp (?<=^|\s)<<smiley regex>>(?=\s|$) I understand only ^ start, | or, \s whitespace, () subpattern, ?=n to match specified n string, $ end of string can't follow the overall effect :)

Comment: http://regex.larsolavtorvik.com/ i'm testing here this regexp on javascript and it's not working (doh) :)

Comment: JavaScript happens to be one of the few regex flavors that don't know [lookbehind assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) (check that link out for an explanation of my regex).

Comment: Aha, so your regexp reads like that. It replaces if patterns(in middle) is at begining or have whitespace in front and pattern is followed by whitespace or end of string.

Comment: It's too hard for me to figure out working example in javascript Regexp

Comment: I have finished parser for skype smiles. It was kinda huge experience. :) Thanks again for tips