# Skype source files with smiles regex patterns

Tags: regex, skype

Anyone knows where to get skype source files with regex patterns for smiles?

Want to understand how they are working.

I have spend few days trying to recreate exact smiles recognition and yet haven't figured proper pattern.

Can anyone provide some info about it?

Thanks ;)

Comment: Perhaps they're not matched using regex in Skype...

Comment: @Beck, what I mean is that internally, Skype might not use a regex to find these smileys inside a message.

Comment: Simple string manipulation then?

Comment: Extremely related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5077842/skype-smileys-regexp-patterns-where-how-to-get

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do it with regex.

I'd use a Map, where the keys are the smiley characters and the values are the URLs to the smiley pics. Then I'd iterate over the map entries and replace all found keys with the equivalent values.

Unfortunately you are not saying what programming language this is about, so here's a simple Java implementation:

```
Map<String,String> smileyMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
smileyMap.put(":-)", "simpleSmiley.png");
smileyMap.put(":-(", "sadSmiley.png");
// etc.

String text = null;// wherever you get the text from
for(Entry<String, String> entry : smileyMap.entrySet()){
    text=text.replace(entry.getKey(),
       "<img src=\"http://my.smiley.server/"+ entry.getValue() + "\" />");
}

// now text contains the smileys as HTML images
```

Comment: As i understand it just replaces all matches, doesn't matter where they are located in text. Try entering this in skype chat and will see what i'm talking about :D:Dte:Dst:D:D :Dtest:D:D

Comment: @Beck, sorry, I am not sending that String to anyone. Why don't you say what the behavior is?

Comment: A map means you're replacing it one by one, and not in a single pass (at least the way you've wrote it, you could write a simple parser). Also, you should mind the order - `]:)` is a valid smiley, and so is  `:)`. You probably want to check them by length, from longest to shortest.

Comment: @Kobi a) at one point you'll always use some kind of a map. Either you iterate over the matches and query the map there or you iterate the map and to a global replace. What's better depends on the number of different smileys and the amount of smiley usage b) of course the logic can't be as simple as my example :-)